# EF Query: How to convert zero-count subquery to null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Using EF 4.5, I want to convert a zero-count sub-query (relatedDrivers) to null in the following statement:

```
var query = from car in context.tblCar
                 let relatedDrivers = (from driver in context.tblDriver
                                       where driver.CarId == car.CarId
                                       select driver)
                 select new
                 {
                     CarId = car.CarId,
                     Drivers = relatedDrivers.Count() == 0 ? null : relatedDrivers
                 };
```

But I get the 'NotSupportedException' stating that it is impossible create a null constant value of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1' !
I wonder why this is so hard for Entity Framework to translate this query to T-SQL. Examining a sub-query and returning NULL if the result count is zero doesn't seem to be that much complicated.

Any solution and explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: why you need it to be null and not an empty list

Comment: Will the query pass if you remove the zero check?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty, shouldn't you group by CarID to have a count of their drivers for each car?

Comment: @NikolaMitev: Yes. It passes.

Comment: First thing first - use `!Any()` instead of  `Count() == 0`. They are the same but `Any` will work with Linq to Object as well as Linq to EF.

Comment: @SimonBelanger `Count() == 0` works in L2O...

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Of course it does. But my point is it doesn't work well with EF where as Any will well in both cases. Also, a `Count` will traverse the enumerable, whereas `Any` will only check the existence of the first item (or the first item matching a predicate, if specified).

Comment: Discussing on whether to use Count or Any doesn't relate to the question.

Comment: why not leave it as an empty collection, what the difference that null makes?

Comment: @MEYWD: Duplicate! I answered you yesterday: I want to know why EF works like this(it is somehow stupid)

Comment: You said group by, I don't mean using group by, I mean doing it without is null check

Answer (score 3):

The solution is **IQueriable.DefaultIfEmpty()**. So the query will be changed to:

```
var query = from car in context.tblCar
             let relatedDrivers = (from driver in context.tblDriver
                                   where driver.CarId == car.CarId
                                   select driver).DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 CarId = car.CarId,
                 Drivers = relatedDrivers
             };
```